# python parce csv-ish data

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have such textfile:

```
var1="value1",var2="value2", ...
```

My task is to parce this into python dictionary.
However, there is such line:

```
 var1="somethig of ""Hybrid-Schaum"", something else", var2="value2", ...
```

So I can't just split it on ," and then on ="

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you need to do with "something else"? Just ignore it?

Comment: nope. I'd need it in dict as value

Comment: dict['var1'] = 'somethig of "Hybrid-Schaum", something else'